# How do i subtract time using 4 variables in PIC assembly?

Tags: assembly, pic

I'm developing a stopwatch in assembly using PIC 18F4520, four 7-segment LEDS  displays and a button matrix (actually I'm using only 2 buttons of 16 but still being matrix button).

I need that wherever I press a specific button the stopwatch will start or stop the count, but when it stop, it needs to show the difference between the previous and the current time. For example: previous was 25 sec, and the current is 30, so the program must show 5.

It seems simple but I don't know how do it using 4 variables. (Need 4 for each 7-segment LED)

Like this :

```
unit_second - first 7-segment display
tens_second - second 7-segment display
unit_minute - third 7-segment display
tens_minute - fourth 7-segment display
```

and here's my question:

How do I subtract time using 4 variables?

I'm tried using SUBFW for each variables but something wrong happen

```
 ATUALIZA    ; MAIN LOOP

 TSTFSZ X    ; ( if x = 1 will start showing the current count )
 BRA MOSTRAREAL ;(SHOW CURRENT TIME ON DISPLAY)

 PULA3
 BRA BOTAO1   ;( ANOTHER BUTTON FUCTION - CLEAR TIMER )
 VOLTA



 MOVLW B'11111111'    
 MOVWF TRISD    
 MOVLW  B'11111011'
 MOVWF PORTB  
 BTFSC PORTD,0      ; heres the button in question
 BRA PULA2
 NADA
 BTFSC PORTD,0
 BRA BOTAO
 BRA NADA

BOTAO
TSTFSZ X  ;( if timer stoped will subtract the previous with the current)   
BRA PULA4
MOVF DIF1,W               ;
SUBWF UNI_SEGUNDO,W       ;
MOVWF DIF1                ;     here's the part that i need to fix
MOVF DIF2,W               ;
SUBWF DEZ_SEGUNDO,W       ; 
MOVWF DIF2                ;


 PULA4
 BTG X,0       ; ( START-STOP FUCTION , x=0 - stop x=1 start   )
 MOVF UNI_SEGUNDO,W
 MOVWF TEMP
 PULA2
 MOVLW B'00000000'
 MOVWF TRISD 


TSTFSZ X          ;  (if timer stoped will show the difference )
BRA     CALCULO   ; (counting function)
CLRF TEMP
BRA MOSTRADIF      ; (show the difference function)
```

So that's all. I don't know how to proceed beyond here and I only need this to finish my project.

Comment: Just count the seconds between pushing the button to start the counter and pushing it to stop it.

Comment: IT WORKED PERFECTLY i don't believe that was so simple thank you very much !!!!!!